A question about kernel of R-module homomorphism between tensor products
Question
I want to prove the following conjecture, and I give a proof but I don't know if it is correct:
Let $R$ be a ring, and $Y,Z,N$ be $R$-module
Let $\phi: Y \rightarrow Z$ be a surjective $R$-module homomorphism
Then we can define an induced $R$-module homo
$$
\bar \phi: Y \otimes_RN \rightarrow  Z \otimes_R N: y \otimes n \rightarrow  \phi(y) \otimes n
$$
My conjecture is that $\ker \bar \phi = \ker \phi \otimes N$
My Proof
Part 0
Let $M,N$ both be $R$-modules, and let $H = M \otimes_R N$
Recall the definition of tensor products:
Let $H^* = \{\sum_{\text{finite}}h : h \in M \times N\}$ be the abelian group
Consider the following three sets of elements in  $H^*$

$E_0 = \{(m_0 +m_1 ,n) - (m_0, n) - (m_1, n)\}$
$E_1 = \{(m, n_0 + n_1) - (m, n_0) - (m,n_1)\}$
$E_2 = \{(rm, n) - (m,rn)\}$

Recall that $M \times N$ is abelian, thus $[-(m_0,n) + (m_0 + m_1, n) - (m_1,n)] \in E_0$, too. Similar for other cases.
Let $E = \{\sum_{\text{finite}} e : e \in E_i\}$
Then we have $H = H^*/E$
Recall that, by the definition of quotient group, for any $\mathbb{h} \in H$, we can write
$$
\mathbb{h} = \left(\sum_{\text{finite}} h_{k}\right)  +E
$$
and we have $\mathbb{h} = 0$ iff $\sum h_k \in E$, where $h_k \in M \times N$
Specially
$$
\mathbb{h} = \sum_{\alpha} h_\alpha
$$
Notice that in general we can write $\mathbb{h}$ in many ways, for example
$$
\mathbb{h} = \sum_\alpha h_\alpha = \sum_\beta h_\beta = ...
$$
We call $\alpha, \beta, ...$ index sets
Part 1: A Lemma, and Steps I am not sure
(I am unsure about this part, can I always write $\mathbb{h}$ in the following way?)
Let $\mathbb{h} =0$ and $\alpha$ be an arbitrary index set
Then we can write
$$
\left(\sum_\alpha h_\alpha\right) = \left(\sum_{\alpha_0} e_{0,\alpha_0}\right) + \left(\sum_{\alpha_1} e_{1,\alpha_1}\right)
+
\left(\sum_{\alpha_2} e_{1,\alpha_2}\right)
$$
where $e_{t, \alpha_t} \in E_t$
$$
= \sum_{\alpha_0} (0,n_{\alpha_0}) + \sum_{\alpha_1} (m_{\alpha_1}, 0) + \sum_{\alpha_2} [(r_{\alpha_2} m_{\alpha_2},n_{\alpha_2}) - (m_{\alpha_2}, r_{\alpha_2}n_{\alpha_2})] 
$$
Notice here we use the simplification:
$$
(m_{\alpha_0,0} + m_{\alpha_0,1}, n_{\alpha_0}) - (m_{\alpha_0,0},n_{\alpha_0}) - (m_{\alpha_0,1}, n_{\alpha_0})
=
(0, n_{\alpha_0})
$$
~
Then we can have the following lemma:
Let $M,N$ be $R$-modules, and $0 = \mathbb{h} \in M \otimes_R N$
Then we can write
$$
\mathbb{h} = \sum_{\alpha_0} (0,n_{\alpha_0}) + \sum_{\alpha_1} (m_{\alpha_1}, 0) + \sum_{\alpha_2} [(r_{\alpha_2} m_{\alpha_2},n_{\alpha_2}) - (m_{\alpha_2}, r_{\alpha_2}n_{\alpha_2})] 
$$
for arbitrary index sets $\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \alpha_2$
Part 2
Let $M,M',N,N'$ be $R$-modules
Suppose we have following surjective $R$-module homo

$\phi_M: M \rightarrow M'$
$\phi_N: N \rightarrow N'$

Then we have

$\pi= \phi_M \otimes_R \phi_N$
$\pi: M \otimes_R N \rightarrow M' \otimes_R N: m \otimes n \rightarrow \phi_M(m) \otimes\phi_N(n)$

$\pi$ is also a $R$-module module
~
Now we want to determine $\ker \pi$
Suppose we have

$\pi(m \otimes n) = \phi_M(m) \otimes \phi_N(n) = 0$

Then, by the lemma, we can write
$$
0 = \sum_{\alpha_0} (0,n_{\alpha_0}') + \sum_{\alpha_1} (m_{\alpha_1}', 0) + \sum_{\alpha_2} [(r_{\alpha_2} m_{\alpha_2}',n_{\alpha_2}') - (m_{\alpha_2}', r_{\alpha_2}n_{\alpha_2}')] 
$$
Because $\phi_M,\phi_N$ are surjective, thus $\pi$ is surjective and we have
$$
\{\sum_{\alpha_0} (0,n_{\alpha_0}'): \alpha_0\}  = 
\pi(\ker \phi_M \otimes N) = \pi(U_M)
$$
$$
\{\sum_{\alpha_1} (m'_{\alpha_1},0): \alpha_1\}  = 
\pi(M \otimes \ker \phi_N) = \pi(U_N)
$$
$$
\{\sum_{\alpha_2} [(r_{\alpha_2} m_{\alpha_2}',n_{\alpha_2}') - (m_{\alpha_2}', r_{\alpha_2}n_{\alpha_2}')]: \alpha_2\}  = 
$$
$$
\{\pi\left(\sum_{\alpha_2} r_{\alpha_2} m_{\alpha_2} \otimes n_{\alpha_2} - m_{\alpha_2} \otimes r_{\alpha_2} n_{a_2}\right) : \alpha_2\} = \pi(U_0)
$$
Thus we have
$$
\ker  \pi = \{u_M + u_N + u_0: u_X \in U_X\}
$$
It's obvious that $U_0 = \{0\}$
Thus we can simplify it to be
$$
\ker \pi = \{u_M + u_N: u_X \in U_X\}
$$
~
Moreover, if we know $u_N = \{0\}$, when we have
$$
\ker \pi = u_M = \ker \phi_M \otimes N
$$

Generally, posts in which you provide a complete answer and are looking for verification should (i) be tagged solution-verification, and (ii) as explained in that tag, you should explicitly identify the step that you are unsure about and explicitly state why you are unsure. Otherwise the question is pff-topic as being too broad and lacking focus.

Ok, I will fix that

The claim is wrong since the right hand side of your claimed equation is not a submodule (see the notion of a flat module). Also what you are trying to prove here is right exactness of the tensor product, of which you can find a proof everywhere under this keyword. It is best to prove this without referring to any explicit model of the tensor product. Only the universal property matters, forget about the explicit construction of $\otimes$ (or any other construction such as quotient modules, localizations, etc). Because this will trigger you to write down these awful complicated element proofs.

Thinks for your reply! I will check that
